# Limit the amount of rows returned by table A, but not by table B

Tags: mysql

I obviously had no idea how to work this question, but I'll explain it the best way that I can. This is a query being used to get messages (and message threads) from a database. The query orders the messages by the threads `last_updated` field, then orders the threads by the thread id (to keep it all grouped) then orders the messages in that group by the message tables `message_date` field.

```
SELECT * FROM messages m, message_threads t 
WHERE m.thread_id = t.thread_id 
ORDER BY t.last_updated, t.thread_id, m.message_date;
```

The thing is that I only want to get messages for the most recent 30 threads. I'm at a complete loss how to do this, because the `LIMIT` keyword limits the amount of rows returned in general.

The 30 threads can have an indefinite amount of messages storage in them, meaning if each thread contained 10 messages, then 300 rows would be returned.

Does anyone have a work-around / solution for my problem? Is there a way to use `LIMIT` that I don't quite understand? Perhaps I need to use a join instead? (but I don't have any experience with joins)

**A visual code representation of thread/message storage**

```
var threads = [ 
    { "thread_id": 1, "messages": [
        { "message_id": 1, "content": "Hello" },
        { "message_id": 2, "content": "Hello" },
        { "message_id": 3, "content": "Hello" }
    },{ "thread_id": 2, "messages": [
        { "message_id": 4, "content": "Hello" }
    }
]
```

Basically, I want to return all of the messages for 30 threads.

Comment: JOIN on a subquery with LIMIT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM messages m, 
     (Select * FROM message_threads ORDER BY message_threads.last_updated, message_threads.thread_id LIMIT 30) t
WHERE m.thread_id = t.thread_id 
ORDER BY t.last_updated, t.thread_id, m.message_date;
```

Comment: This is interesting! I didn't know you could use a query in place of a table to use as data.